# SOLR ExternalFileField vs NRT

Tags: solr

I noticed a relatively new feature in SOLR, ExternalFileField. Most examples I've seen have used the example of using page views to measure popularity. I'm wondering why page views would not be indexed as usual and updated using the new near real time features?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The assumption is that the page views would change frequently and reindexing a document is a relatively expensive operation. And, reindexing requires all your fields to be stored, not just indexed, as 'update' is just a full recreation of the record (due to Lucene's storage format).

Comment: Hm...so NRT is good for adding new documents in real time, but not so good for updating a single field in an existing document. Is that correct?

Comment: These are just additive aspects of the operations. Updating a field in Solr/Lucene is an expensive operation whichever way you look at it. NRT makes it easier to update the documents and see them straight away. NRT does not negate the cost of reindexing a field, just becomes a smaller additive cost than a full hard-commit.

Comment: An I mistaken in thinking an external file also needs to be fully reindexed each time it changes? How does the cost of indexing a potentially large file differ from reindexing documents? I'm sure you're correct but I dont understand the difference.

Comment: External file gets reloaded on each commit and it is just stored in memory. Reindexing each document means it gets appended as a new segment in Lucene indexes, all the fields (potentially many) have to be loaded and stored again, all the bitset caches need to rebuilt, etc. 

But frankly, ExternalFileField is a specialist tool and possibly a temporary solution until some better thing comes along, such as updatable [DocValue](http://searchhub.org/2011/05/31/simon-willnauer-column-stride-fields-or-docvalues-and-improving-on-fieldcache/) support... If you don't get/need it (yet) - don't use it.